# Existence of Smallest Integer $ k $ for cyclic subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the linear operator $ T: V \to V $ on a finite dimensional vector space $ V $ over a field $ F $. Choose a nonzero vector $ \boldsymbol{v} \in V $. Let $ k $ be the smallest positive integer such that 
$$
T^{k} \boldsymbol{v} \in \mathrm{span} \{ \boldsymbol{v}, T \boldsymbol{v}, \dots, T^{k-1} \boldsymbol{v} \}
$$
How does one show the existence of such $ k $? Is the well ordering property useful here? Help or hints much appreciated.

Comment: Show that $T^{i}v = v$ for some $i ≥ k$ maybe?  Or at least show it to be in the span of $v$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no such $k$ exists, then for each $k$ the set
$$ B_k = \{ v, Tv, \ldots, T^{k}v\} $$
consists of $k+1$ linearly independent vectors. But since $V$ is finite dimensional the maximum size of a linearly independent set is $\dim(V)$. So when $n=\dim(V)$, the vectors $v, Tv, \ldots, T^nv$ are linearly dependent, from which we get 
$$ T^nv \in \operatorname{span}(v, Tv, \ldots, T^{n-1}v).$$
So the smallest $k$ so that $B_k$ consists of linearly dependent vectors will be at most $n=\dim(V)$.